# Job Scheduler cant find job/service?

Tags: android, job-scheduling

My app needs to do something periodically so I'm trying the Job Scheduler introduced in Android API 21. At this moment I'm just gettingto know it and try the basics. Unfortunately I get an error:

> Java.lang.illegalArgumentException: No such service ComponentInfo{The whole path here to the service class name TestJobService}

I understand this has been solved for some by adding permission to Manifest, but not me. What else can cause this?

This is my code part where I guess it goes wrong:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Exec reaches here...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
JobInfo.Builder builder = new JobInfo.Builder(1, new ComponentName(getPackageName(),TestJobService.class.getName()));
    //runs job service after every 10 seconds
    builder.setPeriodic(10000);
    jobScheduler.schedule(builder.build());
```

I have this in my Manifest:

```
<service
    android:name=".TestJobService"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"
    android:exported="true" >
</service>
```

One thing that confuses me is that I cant manually give job-permission to the app manually in the device settings (I do that to get permission to storage). If the app needs permission for schedualing jobs, shouldn't I have to give permission in the settings?

I really hope someone has the solution for this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you put your service element inside application element and nowhere else. When I did it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />` to the user permissions in the manifest. it did it for me.